# Load Image from XML to XSLT using FOP Apache

Tags: xml, image, xslt, apache-fop

I am trying to load an image from my XML to my XSLT.
I am using XML 1.0.
I found a lot of solutions, but my XML has another construction, so I hope someone is able to help.

This is my XML:

```
<groundplan>
    <drawing mime_type="image/png" url="./Pictures/drawing1.png"></drawing>
    <drawing mime_type="image/png" url="./Pictures/drawing2.png"></drawing>
</groundplan>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>                
            <fo:external-graphic content-height="33mm" content-width="190mm" scaling="non-uniform" src=""/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>        
</fo:table-row>

<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>                
            <fo:external-graphic content-height="33mm" content-width="190mm" scaling="non-uniform" src=""/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>        
</fo:table-row>
```

Is it possible to add the source from my XML?

Thx for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match each drawing:

```
<xsl:template match="/groundplan/drawing">
   <fo:table-row>
     <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>                
            <fo:external-graphic content-height="33mm" content-width="190mm" scaling="non-uniform" src="{@url}"/>
        </fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>        
   </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hello @stefanhegny doesn`t work for me. getting serveral errors when trying to generate pdf

Comment: I think your solution is usefull but i have a large document, thats why this doesn`t work for me

Comment: I see no reason why it should not work for large documents, nor do I see any practitcal alternative at all..

Comment: I don`t have a lot experience yet but I have a xsl template for my whole file and when i use you option and set another template in the middle the end misses some values

Comment: okay, I see the problem. For that I suggest to put up a different question if you need help with that, showing more of the existing xslt and of the input xml. I'm pretty sure someone can make it work